# A magical place, for sure

Tags: knowledge, rebus, literature

[image: puzzle]

What can you buy in the place that I encrypted here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would say that you could buy

> Practical Jokes

Reasoning

> If I've counted correctly, it seems what you have here is **DIAGONAL LEY** repeated **93** times, in other words, [**93 DIAGON ALLEY**](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/93_Diagon_Alley).

Comment: The correct answer is a little bit more detailed and tedious to get :D

Comment: @ThomasBlue Ah, okay, I think I understand

Comment: I bothers me no end that [these magical things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_line) had nothing at all to do with the solution.